# Django 1.3 static files and displaying content using custom views

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

A slight problem displaying an image using custom views.
I have used the request context as required, however the image doesn't show.

My model uses thumbnails creating the image into a folder named "timgs" which lives under static/myapp/timgs

The static files directory displays css/images fine however when it comes to a custom view images do not display.

Ive tried listing the specific folder in settings like this. with no luck.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/myapp/'),
    ("timgs", "/timgs"),
)
```

I would be very grateful if someone would be kind enough to explain what's wrong, maybe provide a simple example.
Thank you.

**view/template**

```
def function(request):
    whatever = ____.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('template', {
        'whatever': whatever,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


    {% for whatever in whatever %}
        <li>{{ whatever.text }}</li>
        <li><img src="{{ whatever.image.thumbnail }}" /></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

**settings**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''  
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')  
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Comment: Dev server or production? If production did you configure the webserver to serve the static files? Post your MEDIA_* and STATIC_* settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must list the **absolute paths** for every static dir

```
STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/myapp/'),
    ('timgs',os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/myapp/timgs')),

)
```

Comment: @Rick, you probably want to use the {{STATIC_URL}} template tag. Then `<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}myapp/timgs/{{whatever.image.thumbnail}}">`

Comment: @Josh Your comment should probably be a separate answer.

Comment: @Apalala, originally, Rick had commented above me asking Chris why he couldn't access the static media. That comment has been removed. Otherwise I would have answered separately :P